# How Can I make the restart function in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen_width = 600
screen_height = 500


fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Pong')


#define font
font = pygame.font.SysFont('None', 30)


#define game variables
margin = 50
cpu_score = 0
player_score = 0
fps = 90
live_ball = False
winner = 0
speed_increase = 0


#define colours
bg = (12, 0, 91)
white = (241, 185, 0)
ball_color = (168, 43, 17)
bar_color = (10, 106, 86)

def draw_board():
    screen.fill(bg)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, white, (0, margin), (screen_width, margin), 2)



def draw_text(text, font, text_col, x, y):
    img = font.render(text, True, text_col)
    screen.blit(img, (x, y))


class paddle():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 20, 100)
        self.speed = 5
        self.ai_speed = 5

    def move(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_UP] and self.rect.top > margin:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -1 * self.speed)
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN] and self.rect.bottom < screen_height:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, self.speed)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, bar_color, self.rect)

    def ai(self):
        #ai to move the paddle automatically
        #move down
        if self.rect.centery < pong.rect.top and self.rect.bottom < screen_height:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, self.ai_speed)
        #move up
        if self.rect.centery > pong.rect.bottom and self.rect.top > margin:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -1 * self.ai_speed)



class ball():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.reset(x, y)


    def move(self):

        #check collision with top margin
        if self.rect.top < margin:
            self.speed_y *= -1
        #check collision with bottom of the screen
        if self.rect.bottom > screen_height:
            self.speed_y *= -1
        if self.rect.colliderect(player_paddle) or self.rect.colliderect(cpu_paddle):
            self.speed_x *= -1

        #check for out of bounds
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.winner = 1
        if self.rect.left > screen_width:
            self.winner = -1

        #update ball position
        self.rect.x += self.speed_x
        self.rect.y += self.speed_y

        return self.winner


    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, ball_color, (self.rect.x + self.ball_rad, self.rect.y + self.ball_rad), self.ball_rad)


    def reset(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.ball_rad = 8
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, self.ball_rad * 2, self.ball_rad * 2)
        self.speed_x = -4
        self.speed_y = 4
        self.winner = 0# 1 is the player and -1 is the CPU


#create paddles
player_paddle = paddle(screen_width - 40, screen_height // 2)
cpu_paddle = paddle(20, screen_height // 2)

#create pong ball
pong = ball(screen_width - 60, screen_height // 2 + 50)


#create game loop
run = True
while run:

    fpsClock.tick(fps)

    draw_board()
    draw_text('CPU: ' + str(cpu_score), font, white, 20, 15)
    draw_text('Sihu: ' + str(player_score), font, white, screen_width - 100, 15)
    draw_text('BALL SPEED: ' + str(abs(pong.speed_x)), font, white, screen_width // 2 - 100 , 15)


    #draw paddles
    player_paddle.draw()
    cpu_paddle.draw()

    if live_ball == True:
        speed_increase += 1
        winner = pong.move()
        if winner == 0:
            #draw ball
            pong.draw()
            #move paddles
            player_paddle.move()
            cpu_paddle.ai()
        else:
            live_ball = False
            if winner == 1:
                player_score += 1
            elif winner == -1:
                cpu_score += 1


    #print player instructions
    if live_ball == False:
        if winner == 0:
            draw_text('CLICK ANYWHERE TO START', font, white, 160, screen_height // 2 -0)
        if winner == 1:
            draw_text('YOU SCORED!', font, white, 220, screen_height // 2 -100)
            draw_text('CLICK ANYWHERE TO START', font, white, 160, screen_height // 2 -0)
        if winner == -1:
            draw_text('CPU SCORED!', font, white, 220, screen_height // 2 -100)
            draw_text('CLICK ANYWHERE TO START', font, white, 160, screen_height // 2 -0)



    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and live_ball == False:
            live_ball = True
            pong.reset(screen_width - 60, screen_height // 2 + 50)



    if speed_increase > 500:
        speed_increase = 0
        if pong.speed_x < 0:
            pong.speed_x -= 1
        if pong.speed_x > 0:
            pong.speed_x += 1
        if pong.speed_y < 0:
            pong.speed_y -= 1
        if pong.speed_y > 0:
            pong.speed_y += 1


    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

I get the code on YOUTUBE
and edit the code a little bits
but I did not add the restart code
How can I make the restart function in pygame?
I just want to over the game when player get a 5 score in the game.
and want to make the game restart.
When the game is overed, the player can restart the game with the button.

Answer (score 0):

To restart you will need to reset any variables that change during the game. Write a function that sets all objects and variables to its initial state:

```py
def reset():
    global player_paddle, cpu_paddle, pong 
    global cpu_score, player_score  
    global live_ball, winner, speed_increase     

    player_paddle = paddle(screen_width - 40, screen_height // 2)
    cpu_paddle = paddle(20, screen_height // 2)
    pong = ball(screen_width - 60, screen_height // 2 + 50)
    cpu_score = 0
    player_score = 0
    live_ball = False
    winner = 0
    speed_increase = 0
```

Call the function when you want to restart the game.

Comment: Thank you for your help. For now, the game count the score infinitely. but I want to stop it when someone gets the 5 score in game. How can I do?

Comment: @kimusihu Anyway: `if player_score < 5:` `player_score += 1`

Answer (score 0):

Have the loop it's own method, call it from a `main()` run, when the game is over and ends, have `main()` ask the user if they want to play again, and if so recall the main loop after setting everything as its default

or

Just have the part that asks again clear and reinitialize all variables as there defaults and let the loop if the user wants to play again